# How to get selected Item text in ActionSelect control in SAPUI5 XML View

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I want to assign an object ActionSelect control in SAPUI5 XML View to get the key/value pair object to get the selected value. I can assign selectedKey(property) to get the selected key but I want both key and value of the selected object. I can achieve this in javascript but then i have to attach each ActionSelect control with the onChange function which I don not want to do as there are quite a number of drop down in my form.
So my question is, Can I achieve this in XML View?

```
        <ActionSelect id="idCountrySAddress" items="{ path: 'countryModel>/results' }" selectedKey="{path: 'pModel>/address/countrySAddress'}"
            change=".onCountrySAChange">
            <items>
                <core:Item key="{countryModel>countryCode}" text="{countryModel>countryDescription}"/>
            </items>
        </ActionSelect>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In this example all your ActionSelects will call the same function (onChangeActionSelect). The function that must be called from the onChangeActionSelect function is in the custom data from the ActionSelect.

```
<ActionSelect forceSelection="false" change="onChangeActionSelect">
    <customData>
      <core:CustomData key="SelectType" value="Address" />
    </customData>
  <items>
    <core:Item key="foo1" text="bar1"/>
    <core:Item key="foo2" text="bar2"/>
  </items>
</ActionSelect>
        
<ActionSelect forceSelection="false" change="onChangeActionSelect">
    <customData>
      <core:CustomData key="SelectType" value="Name" />
    </customData>
  <items>
    <core:Item key="foo1" text="bar1"/>
    <core:Item key="foo2" text="bar2"/>
  </items>
</ActionSelect>
```

onChangeActionSelect function

```
onChangeActionSelect: function(oEvent) {                 
  const oSelectedItem = oEvent.getSource().getSelectedItem();
  const sKey =  oSelectedItem.getKey();
  const sText =  oSelectedItem.getText();
  const fnFunction = "check" + oEvent.getSource().data("SelectType"); //Get function name from custom data

  this[fnFunction](sKey, sText); //Call Function
},
```

Example functions

```
checkAddress: function(sKey, sText) {
  alert("Check Address:" + sKey + " " + sText);
},
checkName: function(sKey, sText) {
  alert("Check Name:" + sKey + " " + sText);
}
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/40k5uzt7/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply AlexP, but my query is that I want to achieve this without "onChangeSelect" function. I am looking for any property/way to bind the object with the control so that when I select from dropdown it will automatically populate both key and value in that object.